# String interpolation in Angular2 event binding

Tags: angular, string-interpolation, angular2-databinding

I'm using an `ngFor` to list my data, and would like to be able to click an element and have it call a method in my component class, identifying which element of the data it is. My attempts basically came to something like this:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="data">
  <span class="table-select" (click)={{"editData(" + item + ")"}}>{{item}}</span>
</ng-template>
```

However that doesn't work and throws this error:

```
Error: Template parse errors: Unexpected closing tag "span".
```

I have thought about just passing `this` and using the native element to figure out which element it is, but that feels dirty and not very *angular* y. So am I doing this wrong? Or is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<span class="table-select" (click)="editData(item)">{{item}}</span>
```

angular will know to look in your component class for the editData method because of the directive (click)

Comment: Oh wow ok, so the interpolation isn't needed, those variables are injected into the scope when that expression gets called, good to know! Thanks!